# MySQL type VARCHAR vs TEXT

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have been asked to add functionality and fix known bugs on a web app(php, jquery, html) that hits a MySQL database.  I noticed that several admin pages were not updating properly. Specifically, the text that was being entered was being cut off at around 20 characters.  After doing some checking on the code, the database routines, and the database field to make sure there were no character limits(the field was declared VARCHAR(60) I believe), I decided to see what would happen if I changed the field to type TEXT.  And it started working!

So that problem is fixed, however, I then read that type TEXT is depreciated and it is recommended to use type VARCHAR.  So the question is, do I just leave it as type TEXT and not worry about it, or do I work on getting it to work as VARCHAR, and does anyone know why VARCHAR is acting up?

Comment: Does the content contain any special characters that might be getting converted into multi-byte? That would pad out the string longer, though I think it would have to be in some kind of kanji to go from 20 chars to 60+

Comment: @JakeSellers "TEXT is depreciated" -> not in MYSQL RDBMS

Comment: It did originally, so I took out all tick marks and such to test and it was still cutting off.

Comment: @Adrian: `VARCHAR` length parameters are specified in *characters* not bytes, so the encoding shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: It can make a difference if the encoding is *wrong*, however. E.g., if the encoding is latin1, and you dump in a bunch of 3-byte UTF8 characters, they will be munged and take up extra characters.

Comment: @swapnesh Ah I see, thanks for catching that.  I won't worry about it for now, as it works, still curious about varchar acting up though.

Comment: @JakeSellers It actually depends upon your requirement along with some interesting points as raised by Adrian..stack is already flooded with answers for comparisons for these ..just check few within the mysql domain